# How to display empty validation message on empty datagrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
     <asp:DataGrid CellPadding="4" CssClass="grdClass" ID="dgrClubListing" runat="server">
                            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="grdAltRow1"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="grdAltRow2"></ItemStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Club Number">
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdHeader1 lblHeaderText" ></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center"></ItemStyle>
<ItemTemplate> <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClubNo") %>' ID="lblClubNumber"></asp:Label>
<input type="hidden"    runat="server" id="hidden1" name="hdnClubId">
    <input type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClubNo") %>'
                                            runat="server" id="hidden2" name="hdnClubNo">


                            </Columns>

                        </asp:DataGrid>
```

how to add empty data messages to the datagrid in asp.net?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If making use of datagrid than you have to code in codebehind file

```
if (dgrClubListing.Items.Count == 0)
{
    lblEmpty.Visible = true;
    lblEmpty.Text = "Empty";
}
```

and put `lblEmpty` label in your html

---

Make use of : `GridView.EmptyDataTemplate Property` 
It shows empty template when there is no data present in bonded datasource.

```
    <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      forecolor="Red"/>

    <emptydatatemplate>

      <asp:image id="NoDataImage"
        imageurl="~/images/Image.jpg"
        alternatetext="No Image" 
        runat="server"/>

        No Data Found.  

    </emptydatatemplate> 

  </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: here i am using </asp:datagrid> instead of </asp:gridview>

Comment: @jos - why dont you make use of gridview instead of datagrid

Comment: yes it gives an error..it is an already implemented project.so i cannot change to gridview

Comment: @jos - ok dont forget to accept answer or upvote if it works for you

Comment: In gridview its working but my requirement is datagrid .

Comment: @jos - for datagridview you have to try as in update this line of code if (dgrClubListing.Items.Count == 0)
{
    lblEmpty.Visible = true;
    lblEmpty.Text = "Empty";
} ...i.e. you need to do manually

Comment: yes .i tried but i want it inside the datagrid.i get it without displaying no datagrid

Comment: @jos - if you want inside than gridview is solution datagrid is not meant for what you are trying....

Comment: I got the solution without displaying the datagrid. by using label. if (dtClubList.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    lblEmpty.Visible = true;
                    dgrClubListing.Visible = false;
                    lblEmpty.Text = "***No Records Found***";
                }